# istanbul with webpack, mocha

Tags: webpack, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm using mocha-webpack to run my tests for a react project.  The reason I"m not just specifying babel in the call to mocha is that I have jsx that references svg files and that blows up when I do it that way.  mocha-webpack works fine.  But I can't get it to work with istanbul.  I have replaced the babel-loader with bable-istanbul-loader, and the compiles and executes the tests but it doesn't output the coverage folder anywhere.

Also, babel-istanbul seems to want to use karma, but I don't use karma since I'm testing in the browser.

loader looks like this:

```
 {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-istanbul'
        },
```

package.config says

```
"test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config ./app/webpack.config-testing.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

I got something to work, with nyc (istanbul commandline). I removed some names of files and changed some data around to make it generic. I found out how to do this here: https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack/issues/19

```
nyc mocha-webpack <testfile> "$@" --colors --webpack-config webpack.config.js --require scripts/mocha-jsdom-setup.js



  <Some React Component />
    ✓ should render the props1
    ✓ should render the props2
    ✓ should render the props 3

  3 passing (29ms)

---------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File                             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
---------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files                        |    70.14 |    12.43 |    91.76 |    71.37 |                |
 <something>                    |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
  <something>        |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
  <something>             |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                |
 <something>|    69.57 |    10.53 |    91.75 |    70.82 |                |
  <something>                  |    69.57 |    10.53 |    91.75 |    70.82 |84 |
 <something>            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
 <something>         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                |
---------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```